# unable to read excel file in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a excel file using bcp command/xp_cmdshell in SQL Server 2005.

```
select @bcpquery = 
       'bcp "SELECT Column1 FROM Tablename"  queryout '+ 
       @fullFileName +' -c -t -U<username> -P<password> -S'+ @@servername
```

And I am not able to read the excel data using below statement

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
         'Excel 8.0;Database=<PATH\filename.xls>;HDR=YES',
         'SELECT * FROM [sheetname$]')
```

I am not able to read file, I believe this is happening due to unicode characters.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: What does "not able to read" mean? Do you get any errors? Why do you think Unicode is relevant? What data type is Column1? Can you open the resulting file in Excel or Notepad manually? If so, does the content look correct?

Comment: When i execute in SQL I get this error :

Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

I am able to open the file manually, and the contents are correct, but it opens with a warning box.

Comment: Are you running this on a 64 bit machine?  The Jet provider does not work on 64 bit.

Comment: No, I am using 32 bit machine

Answer (score 0):

It appears are though you're using BCP to copy the data out as a delimited file, whereas the OPENROWSET call is reading an Excel sheet. Excel is very forgiving when openings a CSV as XLS, but I have no idea if the Jet driver is the same way.

I would suggest using either BULK INSERT to read the delimited file, or ideally SSIS to both export AND import the data.